# Getting attributes from model in json format - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to pull all attributes except for a few out of a model, and convert the data to json format.

A class I defined in my model:

**mdl.rb**

```
class Mdl< ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.get_json
        self.all.pluck(:a, :b, :c).to_json
    end
end
```

This returns:

```
[[0.0,1.0,365.0]]
```

I have 2 questions:

1) How can I have the json return with attribute names? i.e. [a: 0.0, b: 1.0, c: 365.0]

2) Is there a way to pull the attributes based on 'all columns except x, y, & z'?

Answer (score 1):

1) Instead of doing a self.all.pluck, try 
`self.all.to_json` or 
`self.all.as_json`
this will give you the attribute names like you wanted.

2) You can use select, for example:

```
self.all.select(:a, :b, :c)
```

That should work

Comment: Thanks! Using this I am now getting an id: null with my other attributes, is there a way to remove that?  [{"id":null,"a":1.0,b:1.0,c:365.0}]

Comment: Do you want to completely get rid of id? or have the id value as well? If you want the id value, you could add the id to your select.

Answer (score 1):

Common approach currently is to use [ActiveModelSerializers gem](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) for that. It'll allow you to manage your json serialization same way as you manage your views. So first serializer using that will be like this:

```
class MdlSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :a, :b, :c
end
```

and you will be able to render it to json with automatic serializer lookup like this:

```
render json: @mdl
```

ActiveModelSerializers is de-facto standard for Rails 5, and works well in Rails 4.

Comment: Reading up on this, thanks. Is this what I would use if I created an API, or does rails-api use something else?

Comment: Rails-api authors [recommend](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api#serialization) using AMS.